# Can't kill frozen Visual Studio code on mac

Tags: macos, performance, visual-studio-code

Somehow My visual studio code froze  when  It was idle for some time and I was using my Injellij application.

1. When I found, I tried quitting the application by doing **right +click** on visual studio code icon and **quit**- **nothing happened**.
2. Then I tried **force quit -still nothing happened**.
3. opened activity monitor-saw electron(not responding)- tried quit and force quit- still nothing.
4. then tried everything from this post [How to "killall" Visual Studio Code in Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291328/how-to-killall-visual-studio-code-in-terminal?newreg=e161c24c4c714106838b9795514c23b9) -
   still nothing.

Also in taskbar, the vscode icon is not present but if I try to relaunch, I get an error message saying 
***"Another instance of Code is running but not responding

Please close all other instances and try again."***

I am not sure what actually happened but if someone can help me to trace this and fix without restarting my system . I would also be happy if someone can help me find error logs for vscode or macos to investigate what actually happened.
below are app and system information.

**visual studio code**
package name: VSCode-darwin-universal.zip
version : 1.57.1

**system**
mac Os catalina
version 10.15.7

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/6560

Comment: How is that issue relevant?

Comment: Try restarting the computer through the menu bar.

Comment: @PeterNielsen yes a reboot will work but that should not be required and is too severe for this issue. There should be a less intrusive way

Comment: After step 4 were there and elctron or code entries in activity monitor

Comment: @mmmmmm yes - electron(not responding) ,it was always there no matter what I ddi.

Comment: @PeterNielse yes reboot solved all the problem. but I should be able to kill any process without killing the system itself right and if not, then why, that is what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Try

1. kill all node processes
2. Delete the VSCode and all related files
3. Using an app like [app cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)
4. Restart Mac
5. Reinstall the VSCode again, and move it to Applications folder